# Displaying message body from MIME encoded email string

Tags: c#, asp.net, decoding, mimekit

We're discontinuing use of our Lyris ListManager account, but we still have access to the data in our SQL database.  Clients would still like access to the message archives, so we're trying to find a way to take the encoded email message strings in the database and display them in a readable format in the browser.  An example of the string for a single message:

```
--_004_D72176A059CDE746962E56C32F641BE3016734DDEDKCOEX2VKCOAD_
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_D72176A059CDE746962E56C32F641BE3016734DDEDKCOEX2VKCOAD_"

--_000_D72176A059CDE746962E56C32F641BE3016734DDEDKCOEX2VKCOAD_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Testing.  Please reply back if successful.

Thank you


[cid:image001.jpg@01D36CBE.C035BE50]
Jane Doe | Web Content Manager
jdoe@email.com<mailto:jdoe@email.com>

--_000_D72176A059CDE746962E56C32F641BE3016734DDEDKCOEX2VKCOAD_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-micr=
osoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" =
xmlns:m=3D"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns=3D"http:=
//www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii"=
>
<meta name=3D"Generator" content=3D"Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)">
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:"Balloon Text Char";
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:windowtext;}
span.BalloonTextChar
    {mso-style-name:"Balloon Text Char";
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-link:"Balloon Text";
    font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext=3D"edit" spidmax=3D"1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext=3D"edit">
<o:idmap v:ext=3D"edit" data=3D"1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang=3D"EN-US" link=3D"blue" vlink=3D"purple">
<div class=3D"WordSection1">
<p class=3D"MsoNormal">Testing.&nbsp; Please reply back if succ=
essful.<o:p></o:p></p>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal">Thank you,<o:p></o:p></p>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal">Jane<o:p></o:p></p>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal" style=3D"margin-bottom:12.0pt;line-height:12.05pt;te=
xt-autospace:none">
<b><span style=3D"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans=
-serif&quot;"><img width=3D"90" height=3D"36" id=3D"_x0000_i1025" src=3D"ci=
d:image001.jpg@01D36CBE.C035BE50"></span></b><b><span lang=3D"EN-AU" style=
=3D"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;">=
<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b><span lang=3D"EN-AU" style=3D"font-size:10.0pt;fo=
nt-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;">Jane Doe
</span></b><span lang=3D"EN-AU" style=3D"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot=
;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;">|<b>
</b>Web Content Manager<br>
<a href=3D"mailto:jdoe@email.com">jdoe@email.com</a><=
/span><o:p></o:p></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

--_000_D72176A059CDE746962E56C32F641BE3016734DDEDKCOEX2VKCOAD_--

--_004_D72176A059CDE746962E56C32F641BE3016734DDEDKCOEX2VKCOAD_
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="image001.jpg"
Content-Description: image001.jpg
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image001.jpg"; size=1735;
    creation-date="Mon, 04 Dec 2017 12:14:25 GMT";
    modification-date="Mon, 04 Dec 2017 12:14:25 GMT"
Content-ID: <image001.jpg@01D36CBE.C035BE50>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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--_004_D72176A059CDE746962E56C32F641BE3016734DDEDKCOEX2VKCOAD_--
```

Per some recommendations I've seen online, I'm trying to use MimeKit to do the parsing, but I'm not sure how to use it correctly.  Ideally, we'd like to be able to grab just the message body.  I've tried the following:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(row["body_"].ToString());
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
var thisMssg = MimeMessage.Load(stream);
mssg.Text = thisMssg.TextBody;
```

But that results in "Failed to parse message headers."

I've also tried using the QuotedPrintableDecoder:

```
var decoder = new QuotedPrintableDecoder();
var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(row["body_"].ToString());
var output = new byte[decoder.EstimateOutputLength(buffer.Length)];
int used = decoder.Decode(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, output);
mssg.Text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(output, 0, used));
```

That at least outputs something semi-readable to the browser, but there are still headers and encoded text above and below the message.

Any help is appreciated.  Most examples I've seen online deal with decoding an email file; I may be doing something wrong in trying to convert the string to bytes, or I could be totally off base about the whole thing.

---

UPDATE: this is working perfectly for some messages, but for others both the HtmlBody and TextBody are blank.  I suspect I'm using the wrong encoding or something similar.  Here's an example of the headers + body for one of the messages that's not returning anything:

```
Return-Path: <jane.doe@email.com>
Received: from z221.zixworks.com ([199.30.235.221]) by lyris.aosw.org with SMTP (Lyris ListManager WIN32 version 12.1.22); Mon, 17 Jun 2019 13:15:10 -0500
Received: from 127.0.0.1 (ZixVPM [127.0.0.1]) by Outbound.z221.zixworks.com (Proprietary) with SMTP id 66B33E18A0 for <groups@groups.org>; Mon, 17 Jun 2019 13:15:11 -0500 (CDT)
Received: from NAM02-SN1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com (mail-sn1nam02lp2056.outbound.protection.outlook.com [104.47.36.56]) (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 (256/256 bits)) (No client certificate requested) by z221.zixworks.com (Proprietary) with ESMTPS id 77467E3E1C for <groups@groups.org>; Mon, 17 Jun 2019 13:15:07 -0500 (CDT)
Received: from BN8PR08MB5748.namprd08.prod.outlook.com (20.179.78.79) by BN8PR08MB6161.namprd08.prod.outlook.com (20.179.77.220) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.1987.10; Mon, 17 Jun 2019 18:15:03 +0000
Received: from BN8PR08MB5748.namprd08.prod.outlook.com ([fe80::bdd9:7aa6:33e8:8c7f]) by BN8PR08MB5748.namprd08.prod.outlook.com ([fe80::bdd9:7aa6:33e8:8c7f%3]) with mapi id 15.20.1987.014; Mon, 17 Jun 2019 18:15:03 +0000
From: Jennifer Blosser <jane.doe@email.com>
To: test  List <groups@groups.org>
Subject: test subject
Thread-Topic: test subject
Thread-Index: AdUlODR9gfN51vIpRPKLoCMeLjIytQ==
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2019 18:15:03 +0000
Message-ID:  <BN8PR08MB5748C0A8D6881BF572B3B3FE9DEB0@BN8PR08MB5748.namprd08.prod.outlook.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: 
authentication-results: spf=none (sender IP is ) smtp.mailfrom=jane.doe@email.com;
x-originating-ip: [199.87.130.130]
x-ms-publictraffictype: Email
x-ms-office365-filtering-correlation-id: 097c72d7-a379-49ac-dce6-08d6f34fb836
x-microsoft-antispam:  BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(2390118)(7020095)(4652040)(8989299)(4534185)(4627221)(201703031133081)(201702281549075)(8990200)(5600148)(711020)(4605104)(1401327)(2017052603328)(49563074)(7193020);SRVR:BN8PR08MB6161;
x-ms-traffictypediagnostic: BN8PR08MB6161:
x-ms-exchange-purlcount: 4
x-microsoft-antispam-prvs:  <BN8PR08MB6161B55A933D7DEFA32FE4D69DEB0@BN8PR08MB6161.namprd08.prod.outlook.com>
x-ms-oob-tlc-oobclassifiers: OLM:10000;
x-forefront-prvs: 0071BFA85B
x-forefront-antispam-report:  SFV:NSPM;SFS:(10019020)(39860400002)(376002)(136003)(366004)(346002)(396003)(199004)(189003)(74316002)(7736002)(102836004)(99286004)(81166006)(66946007)(73956011)(81156014)(7696005)(2906002)(316002)(786003)(861006)(6506007)(66556008)(66476007)(66616009)(68736007)(26005)(8936002)(476003)(8676002)(76116006)(186003)(6916009)(99936001)(6306002)(55016002)(54896002)(6436002)(44832011)(478600001)(86362001)(64756008)(53936002)(5660300002)(733005)(54556002)(606006)(66446008)(33656002)(6116002)(256004)(25786009)(3846002)(790700001)(14454004)(66066001)(52536014)(71200400001)(71190400001)(486006)(9686003)(236005);DIR:OUT;SFP:1102;SCL:1;SRVR:BN8PR08MB6161;H:BN8PR08MB5748.namprd08.prod.outlook.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:en;PTR:InfoNoRecords;A:1;MX:1;
received-spf: None (protection.outlook.com: vcuhealth.org does not designate permitted sender hosts)
x-ms-exchange-senderadcheck: 1
x-microsoft-antispam-message-info:  pg6USXqqMlMkBtJyhBsn236QA/k0rF3vQc1WC61WuHvtUFLFrPjeTUEQMYlbPZTU5UJKiehb0WLAKiT4R98gsNeqkREMejsaHxqIgNKTAyZbJ57JaHQmWu1rb9LY+gl+AhP+UXX2BM1WKGNxpc2ySYqeERX52xy/6cYrGPYPNoVvDryIGYBJslLwbyBh25k011jjA18szgKSKIhRu3QnN91aBu/7cTlDVY+/+f00xDMb62g4HWOVHzadxvXbmKv2duvVA1hzI/WTCWkJsg6XLXIBJ/gzip8lNGobi+cJ6a8VqY98CHd7z3vh8PE+4GgJv9UOUgrvW/q9Z6/TU8pfVtSh+5np5hhBRmjX80ZOpVzrjPrXufIe1uJ0hD1cIA4Jx4YcJOqQKsP5OQLAsBRj06/+VAKeswwGNbh2judAif0=
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="_004_BN8PR08MB5748C0A8D6881BF572B3B3FE9DEB0BN8PR08MB5748namp_"; type="multipart/alternative"
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-OriginatorOrg: vcuhealth.org
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 097c72d7-a379-49ac-dce6-08d6f34fb836
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-originalarrivaltime: 17 Jun 2019 18:15:03.6434 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-fromentityheader: Hosted
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-id: d21f3866-8fc6-4527-8622-cefa47fe9632
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-mailboxtype: HOSTED
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-userprincipalname: jane.doe@email.com
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: BN8PR08MB6161
X-VPM-MSG-ID: 77fdc5a9-05b8-4e6c-8d21-912176d50a8c
X-VPM-HOST: vmvpm01.z221.zixworks.com
X-VPM-GROUP-ID: 994c5cd5-4e57-4cea-8f46-45e001662312
X-VPM-ENC-REGIME: Plaintext
X-VPM-IS-HYBRID: 0

    --_004_BN8PR08MB5748C0A8D6881BF572B3B3FE9DEB0BN8PR08MB5748namp_
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_BN8PR08MB5748C0A8D6881BF572B3B3FE9DEB0BN8PR08MB5748namp_"

--_000_BN8PR08MB5748C0A8D6881BF572B3B3FE9DEB0BN8PR08MB5748namp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

SWON:  Please see information below about CEU offering from Be The Match in=
 July. Mercury SWON co-moderator:

Be sure to attend our upcoming webinar, Sickle Cell Disease: Exploring Trea=
tment Options and Psychosocial Care.<https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/u=
rl?u=3Dhttps-3A__go.pardot.com_l_566592_2019-2D06-2D10_gmysfg-3Futm-5Fsourc=
e-3DListserv-5Fdet-26utm-5Fmedium-3Demail-26utm-5Fcampaign-3Dhp-5Fwebinar-5=
F3&d=3DDwMFAg&c=3DpOo6bKNCxsIK6eGC4MYY4A&r=3DM89Ut5RE0fhAI4OPWxaYquIrnvWNHf=
gw4xuTI66ezb0&m=3Dc_yC0-6_GJEEXNI3WxSORby7ZMI668MQiTaQiXl-lOs&s=3DRFAiVjmSs=
QOwCOOAFqGIdtAOvr2St6TOLjS19nfvU7M&e=3D>

message body here.


--_000_BN8PR08MB5748C0A8D6881BF572B3B3FE9DEB0BN8PR08MB5748namp_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-micr=
osoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" =
xmlns:m=3D"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns=3D"http:=
//www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii"=
>
<meta name=3D"Generator" content=3D"Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:#0563C1;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:#954F72;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext=3D"edit" spidmax=3D"1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext=3D"edit">
<o:idmap v:ext=3D"edit" data=3D"1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang=3D"EN-US" link=3D"#0563C1" vlink=3D"#954F72">
<div class=3D"WordSection1">
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal">message body here.</p>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class=3D"MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

--_000_BN8PR08MB5748C0A8D6881BF572B3B3FE9DEB0BN8PR08MB5748namp_--

--_004_BN8PR08MB5748C0A8D6881BF572B3B3FE9DEB0BN8PR08MB5748namp_
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="image001.jpg"
Content-Description: image001.jpg
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image001.jpg"; size=3521;
    creation-date="Mon, 17 Jun 2019 18:15:03 GMT";
    modification-date="Mon, 17 Jun 2019 18:15:03 GMT"
Content-ID: <image001.jpg@01D52517.0DFABF70>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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--_004_BN8PR08MB5748C0A8D6881BF572B3B3FE9DEB0BN8PR08MB5748namp_--
```

Does the QuotedPrintableDecoder method need to come into play?  I've reviewed http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Working-With-Messages.htm, but I'm hoping I don't have to manually traverse each part and there's still a way to grab just the message body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're hitting with MimeKit giving you an error about failing to parse the headers is due to the fact that your string is missing the message headers.

What you're effectively doing is asking a MIME parser to parse a message starting half way into the message. You're giving it an impossible task.

You need to combine the original message headers with the above string to produce the original (complete) message source before you can parse it.

Either that or you have to fake the original message headers so that things parse correctly.

Presumably you have the original message headers somewhere in your database?

> Does the QuotedPrintableDecoder method need to come into play? I've reviewed http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Working-With-Messages.htm, but I'm hoping I don't have to manually traverse each part and there's still a way to grab just the message body.

There's generally no need to use any of the low-level decoders (or encoders) yourself.

There are multiple ways to get the message body:

1. Traversing the MIME tree manually (but in general I wouldn't recommend it), but to do this you really need to understand how MIME is structured and how common mail clients will structure their messages. It's not something I would generally recommend unless you are well-read on MIME. (Difficulty: Extreme)
2. Using a [MimeIterator](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MimeIterator.htm). For the most part, I wouldn't bother with this approach unless you want to manually traverse the MIME tree structure without using any sort of recursion. Where this class really comes in handy is if you are implementing something more akin to an IMAP server. Again, you need to understand how MIME works to really make use of this. See the documentation for a simple example on how to use this. (Difficulty: Extreme)
3. Using a [MimeVisitor](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MimeVisitor.htm) subclass to traverse the MIME tree structure. For a good example on how to do this, I would recommend taking a look at the `HtmlPreviewVisitor` class in the example in the documentation. This is probably the best way to do things if you want to "render" the message like a mail client might. (Difficulty: Moderate)
4. If all you want is the quick & dirty way of getting a message body and you don't care about trying to render the message the same way Outlook or GMail do, then you can use the `MimeMessage.TextBody` and/or `MimeMessage.HtmlBody` properties. (Difficulty: Easy Mode)

If I were you, I'd probably choose between the `TextBody`/`HtmlBody` properties and using something similar to the `HtmlPreviewVisitor` class in the example docs. They will be the simplest way to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I haven't worked with raw email strings before, so I didn't even realize something was missing.  I tracked down the header in a different column, and once I combined those I was able to successfully parse the message using MimeKit.  I may be back with other questions, but for now this gets me 90% to where I need to be.

Comment: Ran into a snag - please see the update to the original question.  Do you have any suggestions?  Sorry if I'm overlooking anything really obvious, I'm very new to all this!

Comment: Do you meant the question about how to get the message body? If so, I've updated my answer to explain the ways to do that.

Comment: Thank you - yes, I was hoping to just use the TextBody/HtmlBody properties, but the main question is why those are both blank for some messages.  I added example code for one of the messages where that's the case.  I'm thought maybe I was using the wrong encoding when converting to bytes, but I've tried changing that several times and still no luck.

Comment: The problem looks like it's caused by the fact that `--_004_BN8PR08MB5748C0A8D6881BF572B3B3FE9DEB0BN8PR08MB5748namp` is indented. You'll find this immediately after the top-level message headers. Perhaps do something like `string message = headers.TrimEnd() + "\r\n\r\n" + body` ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I think that may have just accidentally happened when I pasted it into the post.  I tried the trim just to be sure, but same results... are there any other possible red flags?

Comment: If I remove the leading spaces on the first line with that boundary I mentioned above, the `TextBody` and `HtmlBody` properties both work fine for me.

Comment: maybe try `string message = headers.TrimEnd () + "\r\n" + body.TrimStart ();`? I dunno.